# What is the command from shell to delete a database in sqlite?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I need to delete my database using shell. Please help me find the command to DROP/DELETE my wsemp database. I have tried DROP wsemp, DELETE wsemp etc but not working.

Comment: check this http://www.sqlite.org/lang_droptable.html and this http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete your SQLite database using shell command as below:

```
adb shell
cd /data/data
cd <your.application.java.package>
cd Databases
rm <your db name>
```

For more details check out [Examining sqlite3 databases from a remote shell](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html#sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just delete the database file?

Answer (score 0):

Use DDMS in Eclipse.

Or in a shell (emulator or rooted device)

```
adb shell
cd /data/data
cd <your.application.java.package>
cd Databases
rm wsemp
```

or in code

```
context.deleteDatabase("wsemp");
```